# Get the type of a specific property in a union of classes

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of classes with a `body` property, like so:

```js
class Foo {
  body: {foo: string}

  constructor(body: Record<string, string>) {
    this.body = { foo: body.foo }
  }
}

class Bar {
  body: {bar: string}

  constructor(body: Record<string, string>) {
    this.body = { bar: body.bar }
  }
}
```

These class types are then referenced in an object, where they can be picked up and referenced by a string:

```js
const pages = {
  'foo': Foo,
  'bar': Bar
} as const
```

I then have a union type that references all of my classes:

```js
type Pages = typeof pages[keyof typeof pages]
// typeof Foo | typeof Bar
```

How do I get an object that references all the types of the `body` properties of each class in the `pages` object? Something like:

```js
// The values for `fooBody` and `barBody` are types here
{
  'fooBody': {foo: string},
  'barBody': {bar: string}
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoa0BG8AmAngFwoBmiJEALgE4CWAdgOYC+GGWw8D1NArsCrwaAClyESAJQCmXGngA8vRkwA00ZcwB8AShQcs0KgAs6EAHTiC0ALwpo5eCSvnH0NpncYPGUJBgAQmA0+p5WJMjYwZS0Kj6eXDy0AkKi4dAycoqaahqx2nponlgmZpb41nbIONE4FZbBXp4e8YnU0AAOYEzSMFUGAOSOAyQI8KqDUTQj0EE03tCQ0G1U7OhUBB3S0AAK3b22RpvS8KSd+xAA2gDW0gSnR1sPXT0QALpAA)

Comment: In your example `pages` maps to classes (e.g. `Foo`) not to instances of these classes (e.g. `new Foo(...)`). Is this intentional? If yes, can you give an example of what `fooBody` should be? A type or a concrete value?

Comment: Yeah, it's intentional, sorry. I'll edit the question

Comment: Please be aware that `typeof Foo` and `Foo` are different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the pages as an object of name to class (constructor) makes it really difficult, if you turn it to a type then it becomes much easier.

```
type pages = {
  foo: Foo
  bar: Bar
}

type AllBodies = {
  [Property in keyof pages as `${Property}Body`]: pages[Property]['body']
}

const allBodies: AllBodies = {
  fooBody: { foo: 'string' },
  barBody: { bar: 'string' },
}
```